# In R, in list(), the first name is surrounded by `` automatically, Why?

Tags: r, list

In the list, the first component has automatically endowed ``, why ? 
I think it should be $f instead of $`f`.

```
> list(f=c(1,2),h=c(1,2))
$`f`
[1] 1 2

$h
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will happen if you use numeric values as list elements names. This is done to clearly differentiate the list indices (e.g. `list[1]`) from the list names (e.g. `list$'1'` - wrong quotes du to formatting here).

In your example:

```
list <- list(f=c(1,2),h=c(1,2))
$f
[1] 1 2

$h
[1] 1 2
```

The elements `f` and `h` can be accessed through naming or indexing:

```
# Naming
list$f
[1] 1 2

# Indexing
list[1]
$f
[1] 1 2

# Indexing (alternative)
list[[1]]
[1] 1 2
```

On the other hand, if your list names have numbers they will be coerced as non-numeric values to avoid confusion:

```
list <- list("2"=c(1,2),h=c(1,2))
$`2`
[1] 1 2

$h
[1] 1 2

# Naming
list$`2`
[1] 1 2

# Indexing
list[1]
$`2`
[1] 1 2

# Indexing (alternative)
list[[1]]
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: This isn't answering OP's question. OP doesn't have numeric values as list elements names.

Comment: Thank you for quick and kind reply, and also sorry for my idlelazy research.